# Superpool vs CahedConnectionPool in akka

Tags: akka-http

I read about super pool in akka documentation. I am fairly new to Akka. Please help me understand how does superPool work in case I want to specify different connection pool settings for different hosts but send request to all using superpool. Would it take that configuration in consideration?